# Measuring parsing time of a spider built with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to meassure how much time one of my spiders needs for parsing a website. For that purpose, I have the following code:

```
class TestClass():

t0 = 0
t1 = 0

def run_experiment(self, p):
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    d = process.crawl(MySpider)
    d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())

    reactor.run()

    self.t0 = time.time()
    print("t0: ", self.t0)
    process.start()

    self.t1 = time.time()
    print("t1: ", self.t1)

    p.put( (self.t1-self.t0) )

def init(self):
    total_time = 0

    for i in range(22):
        q = Queue()

        p = Process(target=self.run_experiment, args=(q,))

        p.start()
        spent_time = q.get()
        print("t0: ", self.t0, "--- t1: ", self.t1, "    Spent time  = ", spent_time)
        p.join()

        total_time = total_time + spent_time
        print(total_time)


class _main_test():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        testClass = TestClass()
        testClass.init()
```

The problem I am having is that both t0 and t1 have the same value, so it seems like the process has not finished by the time I compute t1. How could I make sure the process has finished by the time I calculate t1 without penalizing the test? (without sleeping the program or similar solutions, as those would increase the tested time).

Comment: Does adding `process.join()` after `process.start()` help? I should warn this blocks the execution of run_experiment.

Comment: I have added that line, but the value of t0 and t1 is still the same.

Comment: Spiders log their start and end time in their [stats](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/stats.html). You could use that.

Comment: That's true, but the problem is that my spider does several things appart from executing the parse method, and I just want to measure this one.